# multiple forms generated by php in one page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a while loop that generates a number of forms containing information that I want to submit later.

I was thinking of renaming all my "name" variables with the ID of the user from the while loop, but how do I call it in the post check?

Here is an example of my code (in reduced version), I can have a multitude of forms.
The 3 important variables are:
the name in button | the name in option | the name of the submit

thank you in advance for your help !

**EDIT** :

To explain simply, I have a list of players with a dropdown of all existing roles and an "add role" button.

By clicking on the "add role" button, I would like it to retrieve the nickname and the role of the button line to send them to my database.

Here a picture to explain:
[image]

```
<?php while($user = $getUser -> fetch()){
<form method="post" action="">
  <p>Pseudo:</p> 
  <button name="pseudo" value="<?php echo $user["id_user"]; ?>">
    <?php echo $user["pseudo"]; ?>
  </button>
 
  <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default">
    <option selected>Choose</option>
    <?php
      $getListRole = $bdd -> prepare('SELECT * FROM role');
      $getListRole->execute(array());
      while($role = $getListRole -> fetch()){
    ?>
      <option name="roleAdd" value="<?php echo $role["id_role"]; ?>">
        <?php echo $role["nom"]; ?>
      </option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" name="addRole">Add role</button>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi @GrumpyCrouton, 

I can put 1 form with different submit buttons? (with different names I guess).
but how to know that these values are attached?

Comment: Add an [<input type="hidden">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) to your forms which holds the value/id of the player for that form

Comment: You already have `<button name="pseudo" value="<?php echo $user["id_user"]; ?>">`. Doesn't that send the user ID when you submit the form?